# Bash Ctrl + R use current text

Tags: bash

I use the reverse-i-search in Bash a lot. But I always type in the start of the command I'm about to use before I realise that I need to search for it.

Is there a way to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> use the input text, so that I don't have to type it again?

By input text, I mean text that I have typed in to the terminal before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

An example:

```
cd ~/some/folder/
cd some/subfolder/
```

I am about to go to a subfolder with [cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)). Before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I will type "cd some/subfolder". That is the input text.

Comment: Hmm.. I also use CTRL+R a lot, but I commonly use any fragment from the desired command line, not just the start. What exactly do you mean by making it use "the input text"?

Comment: I have edited the question to explain myself better

Comment: +1 ... I don't know why people are voting to close. I thought you could yank `CTRL-y` into the reverse search buffer but it appears you cannot. @Claudio have you every started to type halve of something in Bash and not remember and then want to use `CTRL-R` but you have to retype what you had? I have had it happen.

Comment: Quite a lot of times @AdamGent.. hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you can not do this. That is CTRL-R reads directly from the keyboard (at least on Linux) so you can't even paste into the buffer.

The best solution I can recommend is that you consider using [Emacs Shell mode](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ShellMode) which will replace Bash's input with Emacs buffers.

Comment: Thank you, I'm a vimmer, so it is unlikely that I'll use the emacs shell mode though.

Comment: I feel your pain and I'm sorry its a lame answer. Although I like Emacs for some reason I just prefer working directly with my terminal emulator as things that use termcap/curses just work. Some one could write a terminal emulator that buffered input but it would break other things which is exactly the problem the Emacs shell mode.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>aryr</kbd> command.

It looks worse than it is: for a half typed complex command it's quite helpful.

That's a compound command:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>: home
- -<kbd>r</kbd>: open reverse incremental history search and copy the text after the cursor position
- -<kbd>y</kbd>: paste the text
- -<kbd>r</kbd>: look for matching commands

Comment: Cool, thanks. I recently switched to zsh - `CTRL-aryr` does not work there. Do you know a solution?

Comment: I‘m not using zsh, so I cannot offer a first hand suggestion. Probably this works: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97843